# Heterogeneous Views with unknow EditText number

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a dynamicViews (not sure if that's the right word for creating a view from a json file).

I'm getting the schema from a JSON file, I've stepped up the recycleView and its adapter, so far so good, each Recycleview item (must or not) contain a number of EditText whose number is unknown in advance, so based on the Json file, I have to inflate inside.

I searched a lot but the similar solution I found for Heterogene Recycleview: the idea was to use separate layout and inflate each of them according to your needs inside onCreateViewHolder but the developer who published the solution knew in advance what is the combination of all possible views and he just switch.

```
class Adapter_base_Display(private val listener: Display_Fragment,
                           activity: FragmentActivity ,
                           liste_display : ArrayList<DisplaySections>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<Base_DisplayViewHolder>() {
    private val activityIns = activity
    private val liste_display_Recycle_adapter = liste_display


    interface Base_DisplayListener {
        fun onClickeddisplay(position: Int)
    }

    private val items = ArrayList<DisplaySections>()

    fun setItems(items: ArrayList<DisplaySections>) {
        this.items.clear()
        this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun clear() {
        val size: Int = items.size
        items.clear()
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Base_DisplayViewHolder {
        val binding: ItemDisplayBinding =
            ItemDisplayBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return Base_DisplayViewHolder(
            binding,
            listener as Base_DisplayListener,
            activityIns,
            parent,
            liste_display_Recycle_adapter)

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Base_DisplayViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(items[position])

    }
class Base_DisplayViewHolder(
    private val itemBinding: ItemDisplayBinding,
    private val listener: Adapter_base_Display.Base_DisplayListener,
    private val activityIns: FragmentActivity,
    private var parent: ViewGroup,
    private val items: ArrayList<DisplaySections>,

    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root),
    View.OnClickListener {

    init {
        itemBinding.root.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    fun bind(item: DisplaySections) {



        itemBinding.textView2.text = item.name


    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        listener.onClickeddisplay(adapterPosition)



    }



}
```

The EditText I want to inflate multiple time

```
<EditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edittext_isplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

```
data class DisplaySections(
    val id : Int,
    val name : String,
    val createdAt : String,
    val updatedAt : String,
    val displayTypeId : Int,
    val  displayCustomFields : List<DisplayCustomFields> // Contains the elements that will be displayed as EditText
```

The Base layout-Recycleview Item which is common for all scenarios

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_edittext"   // ALl EditText container 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addphoto"
            android:layout_width="316dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ajouter_photo"
            app:tint="@color/clear_grey" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/camera_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ajouter des photos"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plus_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_photo_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use a RecyclerView for this, you'd more likely use a LayoutInflater and inflate these mini-xmls (one xml per view type) into the root layout.

Comment: i think I have to use the RecyclerView because im willing to display a liste of Items, 
inside  each one they have (common view for all+ variable number of EditText)

Answer (score 0):

I going to post the solution I found.
To solve this problem, we absolutely must use a nested RecyclerView;
As I said above, I want to display a list of items with the same common layout (**Imageview** + **Textview**), but the tricky part here is the dynamic part of each item.
For recap:
Each element (may or may not) contain N-1 (EditText), it depends on what it gets from a json file.

- if you want to solve this problem by creating multiple Viewholder and switch depending on which "**ViewHolderType**" you are wrong !, you will just create an infinite layout files, it doesn't make sense.
- if you create more than one (**EditText**) and only change the visibility it may work, but if you get for example 100 EditText from the Json file you are not going to manually create 100 Edittext.
- if you want to programmatically generate an **EditText**, you will affect every item in your view Recycle since you cannot create view inside **OnbindViewHolder** function.

the only way I found to solve this problem is to create a parent-child RecycleView whenever there is an (**EditText**) you send it to the child adapter and you keep your parent element safe in the parent adapter.

You can also put a condition (NULL tester) inside the Parent-**OnbindViewholder** whenever there is no data, you just don't call Child-adapter.

I hope this solution will be useful  to anyone who has had this problem, and if you have another solution I will be very happy to test them.